# What is this soft cased worm-like creature?

Tags: species-identification, species

[image: worm?]Found this creature in the bathroom

Features which ought to help for identification:

1. Size = 1 cm
2. Soft casing
3. Can emerge from either end of its case and thus reverse the direction it crawls.
4. Many tiny legs.
5. Can walk pretty fast.

Found in the middle east

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE!  Interesting creature, can you add more information about the local environment and specify where in the middle east you found this?  Also, what do you mean by "soft shell" — do you mean that the (sandy?) casing is flexible?

Comment: Looks like a plaster bagworm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phereoeca_uterella)